# facebook canvas app install ad not getting published

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

We are facing some issues while publishing Canvas App Install Ads using facebook ads api.

We are getting this error while submitting the Ad. Ad Creative has been successfully created.

Ad Specs:

```
{
  "adset_id":"XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "name":"e2e canvas app create @ app @ 1407",
  "bid_type":"ABSOLUTE_OCPM",
  "creative":{
    "object_id":"XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "actor_name":"e2e canvas app create @ a",
    "body":"e2e canvas app create @ app @ 1407",
    "name":"e2e canvas app create @ app @ 1407",
    "link_url":"LINK_URL",
    "image_hash":"996e9f651b6bc8f86ee7ac83c72f0718"
  },
  "targeting":{
    "genders":["1"],
    "age_max":64,
    "age_min":13,
    "geo_locations":{"countries":["IN","CN","GB","ZA","RU"]}
  },
  "bid_info":"{
    'ACTIONS':0, 
    'REACH':1500, 
    'CLICKS':0, 
    'SOCIAL':0
  }",
  "objective":"CANVAS_APP_INSTALLS"
}
```

Error:

```
Please include a value for 'user_os' or 'user_device' in ad targeting spec.|Exception|1487504
```

Comment: have you tried specifying page_types as a desktop format?

Comment: Yeah thanks Paul found out that this is an official bug reported on Facebook & this is a work around for now.